# How take only the best values from two binary files and make one binary file?

Tags: r, binary, correlation

I have two binary files with the same dimensions: the first represents correlation between xm and df and the second represents also correlation between xm and gh data.I want to create one map out of these two representing the best correlations.for instance:
1- read  the first pixel in the correlation map between xm and df  and the corresponding pixel in the correlation map between xm and gh.

2- take the best correlation value and make it blue color if it comes from xm and df,otherwise make it green if it comes from xm and gh

3- do the same for all pixels

4- get something like the map  associated

Here are the two files:

```
  1- to read the first file correlation map:![enter image description here][1]

   conn <- file("C:\\corr.bin","rb")![enter image description here][2]
  corr<- readBin(conn, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
  y<-t(matrix((data=corr), ncol=720, nrow=1440))
    image(y)
```

2- to read the second file land cover map:

```
  conne <- file("C:\\cor06.bin","rb")
  over<-readBin(conne, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
  y1<-t(matrix((data=over), ncol=720, nrow=1440))
  image(y1)
```

3-to write the results:

```
     to.write = file(paste("/orcomplete.bin",sep=""),"wb")
     writeBin(as.double(results), to.write, size = 4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dimensions of your data are the same (which in your case this is true) then you can use the `raster` package like so:

```
r <-raster(t(matrix((data=corr), ncol=720, nrow=1440)))
r1 <- raster(t(matrix((data=over), ncol=720, nrow=1440)))
m <- r > r1 #Compare the two rasters
image( m , col = c("#EF8A62" , "#67A9CF" ) ) #Hexadecimal colour specification
legend( "bottomleft" , legend = c( "Y" , "Y1") , fill = c("#EF8A62" , "#67A9CF" ) , border = "#D9D9D9" , bty = "n")
```

[image]

Comment: what a bout the colors of the best?which is which?

Comment: `m <- overlay( r , r1 , fun=which.max )`
Error in setValues(out, vals) : values must be a vector

Comment: @Barry What are r and r1? Did you leave them as a matrix? They should be rasters of your data x and y? If I do `y<-t(matrix((data=runif(100800)), ncol=720, nrow=1440));x<-t(matrix((data=runif(100800)), ncol=720, nrow=1440));y <- raster( y );x <- raster( x );m <- overlay( x , y , fun=which.max )` it just works. (100800 is the number of elements in your binary files)

Comment: well I can't really help with NO details about the data. Try `x<-raster( t( matrix( data=as.numeric( corr ) , ncol=720, nrow=1440) ) ); y<-raster( t( matrix( data=as.numeric( over ) , ncol=720, nrow=1440) ) )`

Comment: the two files are added to my question.you could give it a try

Comment: @Barry as you asked so nicely I updated code to your specific example. The problem was the NA's in your data were causing `which.max` to break. However, there is an even easier solution...

Comment: So please share the  easier solution

Comment: Many thanks for your  perfect solution .it would be nicer if you add some explinations for example: `m <- r > r1`   #####  `("#EF8A62" , "#67A9CF" )`  Y represent r and Y1 represent r2??

Comment: @Barry It would be nicer if you pressed the green tick on my answer and/or upvoted it so I could earn those reputation points for taking my time over your problem.  However since I like to help, `("#EF8A62" , "#67A9CF" )` is just me specifying colours using hexadecimal codes instead of names. You could just as easily use `c("red" , "blue" )` but the colours aren't as nice. As for `m <- r > r1` it compares each value of r against r1 and returns true if it is greater or false if less. So where m was true r was best, where m was false r1 was best

Comment: How true  or false is then represented on the map? Y and Y1 confused me!! which is r and r1  pleas?

Comment: Sorry I used Y and Y1 to mean r and r1 respectively. T/F, 0/1, it doesn't really matter. One corresponds to r the other to r1. I suggest you do some reading of the manuals for eg `raster` etc.

Answer (score 1):

An example with base R:

```
## example data
set.seed(1)
cor1 <- runif(100)
cor2 <- runif(100)

## find max correlation
maxCor <- pmax(cor1, cor2)
## find correct color
col <- ifelse(maxCor==cor1, "blue", "green")
```

Comment: so the blue for cor1 and the green for the cor2?

Comment: I tried to plot but got errors.could you please plot your results

Comment: This will create a matrix of words of green or blue.I meant the colur it self not to produce matrix with green and blue words!